# 've installed a MySQL server onto my computer and when I first installed it, now I've xampp and no work mysql , what file do I need to run

Tags: mysql, xampp

've installed a MySQL server onto my computer and when I first installed it, it ran automatically, now I've restarted my computer it is no longer running, what file do I need to run to get it back up and running again?

Comment: That obviously depends on the type of system you are working on which you did not tell us.

Comment: i want to work on xampp and i uninstall mysql i no needed in win10

Comment: Ah, sorry, I cannot help with MS-Windows environments.

Comment: Follow this tutorial to start/stop mysql server from command line in Windows. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

**For linux environment**

go to terminal

```
$ mysql -u user_name -p'password'
```

password without quotes just after -p

**For Windows Environment**

The MySQL server can be started manually from the command line. This can be done on any version of Windows.

To start the mysqld server from the command line, you should start a console window (or “DOS window”) and enter this command:

```
shell> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld"
```

The path to mysqld may vary depending on the install location of MySQL on your system.
You can stop the MySQL server by executing this command:

```
shell> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqladmin" -u root shutdown
```

**Note :**

If the MySQL root user account has a password, you need to invoke mysqladmin with the -p option and supply the password when prompted.

This command invokes the MySQL administrative utility mysqladmin to connect to the server and tell it to shut down. The command connects as the MySQL root user, which is the default administrative account in the MySQL grant system. Note that users in the MySQL grant system are wholly independent from any login users under Windows.

If mysqld doesn't start, check the error log to see whether the server wrote any messages there to indicate the cause of the problem. The error log is located in the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data directory. It is the file with a suffix of .err. You can also try to start the server as mysqld --console; in this case, you may get some useful information on the screen that may help solve the problem.

The last option is to start mysqld with the --standalone and --debug options. In this case, mysqld writes a log file C:\mysqld.trace that should contain the reason why mysqld doesn't start. See MySQL Internals: Porting to Other Systems.

Comment: The `mysql` executable typically is the _client_ program used to connect to a running mysql server. So this quite certainly is _not_ what the OP is asking for.

Comment: 11:06:06 PM  [mysql]  MySQL Service detected with wrong path
11:06:06 PM  [mysql]  Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
11:06:06 PM  [mysql]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:06:06 PM  [mysql]  Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
11:06:06 PM  [mysql]  Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
                                                                                      its a write problem